# Is it possible to give a single Odds Ratio for two independent variables?

Tags: regression, logistic, odds-ratio, tables

I have been asked by co-authors on a paper to fill in the Odds Ratios marked as (?) in a table like the one below.

| Country of origin | Land A (Odds Ratio) | Land B (Odds Ratio) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Number of people who meet the outcome of interest | 12 (?) | 4 (?) |
| Median age | 33 (?) | 28 (?) |
| Number of males | 16 (?) | 14 (?) |
| Number of females | 17 (?) | 14 (?) |

Would you need to run a multivariate logistic regression to obtain an OR while considering both independent variables (Land A = Yes, Male = Yes) in relation to the dependent variable (Outcome of interest = Yes)?

Or am I on the wrong track entirely? Intuitively I feel like this isn't right somehow.

Comment: Odds ratio is composed of two odds, which are composed of probabilities. You don't have either in this table.

Comment: You have three independent variables: Age, sex, and land.

Comment: What about in the case of cell B4, reading 16? In the context of the table, I would take this to mean outcome ~ land + sex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this would be multiple logistic regression, not multivariate. The latter term applies when there are multiple outcome or dependent variables. Also, the cells mix counts and statistics.

Second, this table is oddly formatted and doesn't seem to contain the information needed to run a logistic regression. If "outcome of interest" is the DV, then it should be the columns and Land should be one of the rows.  And "median age" won't work well.

If you have the raw data, then you can use any statistical program to run a logistic regression along the lines of

```
outcome ~ land + age + sex
```

(with details depending on the program you use). The output will include ORs for each independent variable.